# MCS_Chembl inhibitors for SET-family of protein

Tags: r

I'm attempting to cluster a few molecules to find their most common structure.

My dataset from CHEMBL had been retrived using the protein ID and IC50.
I don't understand how to use R, and I can't seem to find any tutorials that use an excel database as an input.
Any recommendations?

I've already installed rcdk and Chemminer.

[image]

I've tried using the tutorial's scripts [ChemmineR: Cheminformatics Toolkit for R](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ChemmineR/inst/doc/ChemmineR.html#ChemmineR:_Cheminformatics_Toolkit_for_R), but I'm not sure how to get it to work with an Excel dataset as input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rcdk

```
    library(rcdk)
    read in the test dataset of compounds and targets
data<-read.csv("testKinase.csv",header=T)

#parse the smiles from the compounds
Smiles<-lapply(as.character(data[,2]),parse.smiles)
fps<-lapply(Smiles,get.fingerprint,'extended')
cmp.fp = vector("list",length(Smiles))

for (i in 1:length(Smiles)){
  
  cmp.fp[[i]] = lapply(Smiles[[i]], get.fingerprint, type="extended")
  
}
fp.sim = fp.sim.matrix(unlist(cmp.fp))
idxs<-which(fp.sim > 0.95,arr.ind=TRUE)
idxs <- idxs[idxs[,1] > idxs[,2],]

rownames(data)<-data[,1]
data[is.na(data)]<-0
```